# Check file version from file full path

Tags: wix, wix3.11

I need to check service executable version before proceed my installation.

I have read full path for registered service, from registry:

```
    <Property Id="SOME_SERVICE_PATH">
       <RegistrySearch Id="FindServicePath" Type="raw" Root="HKLM" Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TARGET_SERVICE" Name="ImagePath" />
    </Property>
```

After that I tried to perform file search like below:

```
  <Property Id="TARGET_SERVICE_UNSUPPORTED">
    <DirectorySearch Id="ServiceParticularVersionSearch" Path="[SOME_SERVICE_PATH]">
        <FileSearch Name="Service.exe" MaxVersion="2.5.0.1"  /> 
    </DirectorySearch>
  </Property>
```

And this not ganed me results.

I suppose the problem is in the value I passed to *DirectorySearch* `Path` property.
According to the Wix documentaion `Path` should be initialized with 
"Path on the user's system. Either absolute, or relative to containing directories" 
Unfortunately, there is no place in the registry I can read service installation directory. This is 3d party component.

Are there any solutions here? important moment - Its forbidden to use custom actions in our project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, the answer was in `Type` parameter of `RegistrySearch` element. If I assign "file" to it, I will be able to apply `FileSearch` on path I read and check executable version.
Another solution here is to use remark from [RegistrySearch Element documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/registrysearch.html)

> **file**
>
> The registry value contains the path to a file. To return the full file path you must add a FileSearch element as a child of this element; otherwise, the parent directory of the file path is returned.

I mean "otherwise, the parent directory of the file path is returned"

**Solution 1**

```
  <Property Id="TARGET_SERVICE_UNSUPPORTED">
    <RegistrySearch Id="FindServicePath" Type="file" Root="HKLM" Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TARGET_SERVICE" Name="ImagePath" />
        <FileSearch Name="Service.exe" MaxVersion="2.5.0.1"  /> 
    </DirectorySearch>
  </Property>
```

**Solution 2**

```
<Property Id="SOME_SERVICE_PATH">
   <RegistrySearch Id="FindServicePath" Type="file" Root="HKLM" Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TARGET_SERVICE" Name="ImagePath" />
</Property>

<Property Id="TARGET_SERVICE_UNSUPPORTED">
  <DirectorySearch Id="ServiceParticularVersionSearch" Path="[SOME_SERVICE_PATH]">
    <FileSearch Name="Service.exe" MaxVersion="2.5.0.1"  /> 
  </DirectorySearch>
</Property>
```